# Числа с плавающей точкой в нормальный формат

Tags: php, bitcoin

Здравствуйте. Работаю с bitcoin через json-rpc. Часто выдаются балансы с плавающей точкой, например 2.87E-5(допускаю что такие числа называются по-другому). Пытаюсь преобразовывать их с помощью функции number_format($num,8), но заметил что баланс не всегда правильный. Какой правильный способ преобразования?

Comment: в чем неправильность?

Comment: Небольшое смещение, я подозреваю что происходит округление

Comment: @DSerdiuk не нужно хранить цены во _float_ из-за проблем с округлением: [Точность чисел с плавающей точкой](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php) Храните значения в _integer_ . Ну или используйте [математические расширения](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.math.php)

Comment: гы... с такими курсами скоро байта порядка не будет хватать )) если баланс выше 5.0E-217 то можно выходить на пенсию ))